# What is the time complexity of this Scheme exponentiation function?

Tags: algorithm, math, scheme, time-complexity

What is the time complexity? Why?

```
(define (mult a b)
      (define (internal a accum)
        (if (= a 1) accum
            (internal (- a 1) (+ accum b))))
      (internal a b))

(define (to-the-power-of m n)
  (define (internal x accum)
    (if (= x 0) accum
        (internal (- x 1) (mult accum m))))
  (internal n 1))
```

Comment: These look, um, familiar - did I write these for you a week or so ago?

Comment: Watch your indentation style ? We might think that the function `to-the-power-of` is part of the function `mult`

Answer (score 3):

the time complexity for the mult part can be found like this:

to calculate (mult a b), (internal a accum) is called until a = 1
so we have some kind of tail recursion (loop) that iterates over a.

we thus know that the time complexity of (mult a b) is **O(a)** (= linear time complexity)

(to-the-power-of m n) also has an (internal x accum) definition, that also loops (until x = 0)

so again we have **O(x)** (= linear time complexity)

*But*: we didn't take into account the time needed for the function calls of internal...
In internal, we use the (mult a b) definition which is linear in time complexity so we have the following case:
in the first iteration mult is called with: (mult 1 m) --> O(1)
second iteration this becomes: (mult m m) --> O(m)
third iteration: (mult m² m) --> O(m*m)
and so on
It is clear that this grows until n = 0 (or in internal this becomes x = 0)

thus we can say that the time complexity will depend on m and n: **O(m^n)**

[edit:] you can also take a look at a related question I asked earlier: [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculateapproximate-it) which may give you a clue how you can handle the approximation more generally

Answer (score 0):

Assuming addition and multiplication are both counted as a single operation, this function performs O(m^n) operations.

First consider the mult function. It (mult a b) will perform exactly a-1 additions. Since, the asymptotic growth is the same, lets approximate this by a, for mathematical simplicity.

Now for the to-the-power-of function, this performs n calls to the mult function. These calls are to (mult 1 m), yield m, then to (mult m m), yielding m^2, then to (mult m^2 m), yielding m^3 and so on upto m^n. So the total number of operations performed here is the sum m^0 + m^1 + ... + m^n. This is (m^n - 1) / (m-1) which grows as m^n.